# python / pandas - write file using length of table columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to write the contents of a pandas dataframe (or database table if it's not possible with pandas) and each column in the row needs to have the length of that column as stored in the database. For example, if I have a 'name' db column that is 10 characters in the database table, I want to write it to the file with a length of 10. If it's 'Joe' it would be written as 'Joe' followed by 7 spaces, before the next column appears.

Is there a way to easily do this?   I have a number of tables to do this for so ideally, I'm able to do it without explicitly specifying the length for each column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be done by your DB server, if not, you can format your data with `.str.pad` or `.str.ljust`.

Comment: Can you give some specifications about your database? You have a single pandas dataframe, and a single SQL table or something else? You also mention a file, which is a third place for data separate from the pandas dataframe, and from the database?

Comment: To clarify - I'm querying DB2.  I have a number of tables I need to loop through, query, and then export that data to a file where each column retains the length of the column in the database. Basically, I just need to write the table data to this file. But I have a number of tables so I'll loop through them and create 1 file per table. I don't need to use dataframes if it doesn't make it easier.  The real problem is how I write that file with the appropriate width for each field.